# Why can I rearrange my Apps Grid for some accounts but not others?

Tags: google-workspace

On my main Gmail account, I'm able to rearrange all the icons in my app grid. So I've ordered them like this:

[image]

However, I have another account (my work account) which is on Google Apps for Business. I have an app grid there, too, but I can't do anything with it. When I try to click and drag the icons on that one, they don't move. So it's stuck like this:

[image]

I would really like to be able to reorganize this grid as well, though. Is there some administrative setting in Google Apps for Business that would allow me to sort these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t do it for a Google Apps account.

See the note under *Customize your menu* in [this help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464):

> Note: If you are using a Google Apps account, you won't be able to customize your menu.

Answer (score 1):

I just went into *Chrome -> Settings -> Extensions* and searched for *App Launcher Customizer*, which found the same extension linked in David F's answer above.  I installed it.  Then, I went back to *Settings, App Launcher Customizer, Options* and it presented me with an interface for rearranging the icons in my Google Apps grid.

Note that this works for the Google Apps grid that appears within many Google apps.  It is **not** the same as the Apps menu in the Google Toolbar on the Chrome browser, or Windows toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Download this Chrome extension http://www.carlosjeurissen.com/app-launcher-customizer-for-google/
(obviously you'll need to use Chrome for this).. Go into your browser settings, choose *Extensions*, then select *App Launcher Customizer*, and select the *Options* link.

Comment: I would be very careful with installing extensions from other places than the Chrome Web Store.